# Dynamic colouring of created rectangles on Tree Chart in Amcharts

Tags: angular, tree, amcharts, amcharts5

So I wanted to change the amcharts tree-chart's design by changing the default circles into rectangles. I've done this by hiding the circles with the code:

[image]

I have then added rectangles in a similar way to the 'Using images' section in the amcharts5 Tree documentation --https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/hierarchy/tree/#Using_images . This can be shown in the code below:
[image]

However, the target.dataItem value seems to come out as undefined when I log it. Target is extended by type am5.LinkedHierachyNode. My data is in format:
[image]. This is the same as in the example except with the added propertie of 'color'. Any help on how I can get this to work would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being that you have to add 'target.events.on('dataitemchange', (value) => {})' and use value.target.dataItem.dataContext to get the value.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.